# Creating read-only fields using Google Contacts API

Tags: java, google-api, google-contacts-api

I've been trying to add a google contact using the Google Contacts API, that has some custom field that can be modified only by the google application I'm creating while remaining read-only for the user.
The problem is that after use the method and update the contact

https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/IEntry

```
 void   setCanEdit(boolean canEdit)
          Sets whether the server allows this entry to be modified by the client.
```

The field can still be edited from the user that has the email.

Am I using the right method? Does anyone have a sample for similar thing because I couldn't find one on the Internet?

Is it possible to set some access restriction (for example to set contact read-only, or only editable)

Comment: You ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Nope, we've used some kind of workaround. setCanEdit just didn't function at the time

Comment: How did you workaround this problem? Could you please describe the way you went?